# Sync Eclipse project between Linux and a windows computers

Tags: windows, linux, synchronization

My situation is like this:
I got a windows computer and a Linux computer , and an Eclipse project I'd like to sync between them. What is the best way to do this ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

Use a version control system, such as [git](http://git-scm.com/) or [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/).

Answer (score 0):

This is how we do it:

We have a linux file server running Samba (this allows Windows boxes to connect to it), install a CVS server, point your Eclipse installations at your CVS directory.

Can't offer much more info than that, but I think an CVS / file server based on Linux (we use Ubuntu) and samba is the best option.

Comment: Why do you need the samba?  Can't you just check files out of CVS directly onto your windows and linux box?  (Not that I would want to use CVS anymore, with Subversion being better and just as cheap)